# Compute Distance Using Absolute Positions (X,Y)

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial, spatial-query

I've added a geography column to my table (MICROSOFT SQL SERVER) and inserted geography point data in it (4326).
Now I am able to compute distance of all points from a specific point using below query:

```
DECLARE @X geography = geography::Point(0, 0 , 4326);
SELECT TOP(4) *, LOCATION.STDistance(@
FROM [ADDRESS] A
WHERE A.LOCATION IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY LOCATION.STDistance(@X) ASC
```

and it works. However I would like to compute distance using Euclidean distance formula: sqrt((y1-y2)^2 + (x1-x2)^2)) and would like to have two separate columns for x and y positions if it's possible.

Comment: Absoulte Positiones - that french ?

Comment: Yes, SQL server has a [SQRT function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176108.aspx) so you can just implement that yourself using two columns can't you? But there's the [geometry type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280487.aspx) for Euclidean distances which will do this all for you, albeit stored in a single column.

Comment: What is the difficulty that you're having?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Rup :) 
I changed the type from geography to geometry with SRID 0!

```
UPDATE [ADDRESS]
SET LOCATION = geometry::Point(1, 1, 0)
WHERE ADDRESSCODE = 4


DECLARE @X geometry = geometry::Point(0, 0 , 0)
SELECT TOP(4) *, LOCATION.STDistance(@X)
FROM [ADDRESS] A
WHERE LOCATION IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY LOCATION.STDistance(@X) ASC
```